# Matplotlib - how to underline the x-axis ticklabels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I was trying to underline xticklabels using `plot.rc` but

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
xtext = plt.xticks()
xtext[0] = tuple(r'\underline{}'.format(x) for x in xtext[0])
```

But the above code gives me an error `'tuple' object does not support item assignment'

Same error with:

```
xtext[1] = plt.text(0,0,r'\underline254')
```

Here, `xtext[0]` is an `ndarray` of `x-axis label values` and `xtext[1]` is an `silent_list` of `Text xticklabel objects`

How can I underline the xtick labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following solution. Here I am creating a new list of modified tick labels with underscores. Then I assign them as the new tick labels using the axis object `ax` and `set_xticklabels`. I have replaced the `format` with the old style of string formatting using `%` as for some reason, the `format` method underlines only the first character.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(range(5))
xtext = plt.xticks()

xtext_new = [r'\underline{%s}' %x for x in xtext[0]]
ax.set_xticklabels(xtext_new)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In my case it just wrote `\underline` plus the xtick label :(